# Parse local json file to object

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I have this code:

```
struct ProductObject : Codable {
    let palletHeight : Double?
    let layerPallet : Int?
    let prepCombisteamer : String?
    let id : Int?
    let avikoWorlds : [String]?
    let avikoSegments : [String]?
    let sunFlower : Bool?
    let inPieces : Bool?
    let noBox : Int?
    let prepFryingPan : String?
    let packageContents : Double?
    let carbohydrates : Int?
    let fat : Double?
    let eanBox : Int?
    let weightYieldPercent : Int?
    let kcal : Int?
    let markedAsFavourite1 : Bool?
    let avikoPodSegmentyRynku : [String]?
    let prepPot : String?
    let prepMicrowave : String?
    let name : String?
    let code : Int?
    let prepDeepFryer : String?
    let avikoConcepts : [String]?
    let boxLayer : Int?
    let avikoSegmentyRynku : [String]?
    let active : Bool?
    let shelfLifeTimeFrame : String?
    let markedAsFavourite2 : Bool?
    let palletWeight : Double?
    let changeTime : ChangeTime?
    let kj : Int?
    let langVersions : [LangVersions]?
    let proteins : Double?
    let markedAsFavourite3 : Bool?
    let containsGluten : Bool?
    let regions : [Int]?
    let eanFoil : Int?
    let shelfLife : Int?
    let contentPerBox : Int?
    let prepOven : String?
}
func downloadImagesFromJsonProductFile(fileName: URL){

        let filePath = fileName.path
        let fileManager = FileManager.default
        if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: filePath) {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileName)
                let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode(ProductObject.self, from: data)

            } catch let error {
                self.errorLoginMessage(txt: "MainView - Error 109: Problem with parse file \(error)", title: "Blad".localized())
            }
        }
    }

downloadImagesFromJsonProductFile(fileName: documentsDir.appendingPathComponent((AppGlobalManager.sharedManager.loggedUser?.selectedLanguage)! + "/json/products.json"))
```

My local json file: https://files.fm/u/73n845ty

When I run function: downloadImagesFromJsonProductFile I have error
(when app was started): Problem with parse file typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary, Swift.DecodingError.Context(coding-path:[], debugDescription: "Expected the decode Dictionary but found an array instead.", underlyingError: will).

How to fix it?

Comment: let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProductObject].self, from: data)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I review your JSON here http://json.parser.online.fr/, there is array as root object, therefore you should do

```
let json = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProductObject].self, from: data)
```

**UPDATE**

Please create `JSON struct Codable` from here [json4swift](http://www.json4swift.com/), please resolve type mismatch errors first otherwise your JSON could not be parsed and you will get type Mismatch errors.

You can get product code by following,

```
let jsonData = try JSONDecoder().decode([ProductObject].self, from: data)

for detail in jsonData {
    print(detail.code ?? "")
}
```

Comment: It's working. How can I iterate after this? for products in jsonData {
                    for productDetails in products{
                        print("Product code : \(productDetails.code)")
                    }
                } not working :( I have error: Type 'ProductsObject' does not conform to protocol 'Sequence'

Comment: jsonData itself contains ProductObject

Comment: can you show me how? I need print all productDetails.code

Comment: give me few mins

Comment: thank you. I have error in print line: Value of type 'ProductsObject' has no member 'code'